# Export R script without output to PDF/Word

Tags: r

Is it possible to export the R script to a PDF and/or Word document without the outputs (i.e. without whatever the console prints; plots, graphs etc.)? I know about the `r markdown` package but as far as I know, it exports the script only with outputs.

Answer (score 1):

rmarkdown is very flexible, you don't have to include output. If you set the option `eval = FALSE` none of the code will be evaluated, so no outputs will be generated.

[See here for a detailed list of options](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/) available at the code-chunk level.

Comment: Is there a similar option for `rmarkdown::render` ? I just wanted to export something really quickly and don’t really understand how to use `knitr`

Comment: They're basically the same. Put `eval = FALSE` in your chunk options.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on @GregorThomas's answer: if you simply add R code block-formatting around all of your code with `eval=FALSE` specified and save it with an `.rmd` extension, you can then click "Knit to PDF" in RStudio (which will automatically add a minimal header). I think you could probably also do `rmarkdown::render("myfile.rmd", output_format = "pdf_document")`.  If you wanted you could set up a little script to do the minimal editing and rendering automatically ...

````
```{r eval = FALSE}
x <- 2+3
print("hello")
```
````

Something like (untested!)

````r
printme <- function(file) {
   tt <- tempfile(fileext = ".Rmd")
   writeLines(c("```{r eval=FALSE}",
              readLines(file),
              "```"),
         tt)
   rmarkdown::render(tt, output_format = "pdf_document", 
                     output_file = "out.pdf")
}
````